# Search engine for popular parts

Tags: component-selection

I'm using OctoPart dozens of times each day to check availability, pricing, specs, datasheets etc. However, I sometimes look for "popular parts", either when specs aren't that special or as a starting point to find suitable components. I know that "popular" is pretty vague, but is there any component search engine that has some kind of useful ranking other than price or the "relevance" sorting OctoPart does? I want to use common parts when possible, to ensure low price and good sourceability.

Comment: What does the relevance sorter accomplish?

Comment: Usually I search Mouser/Digikey for a part, then sort by "stock". The ones with the most stock are usually the most popular, then I just pick the one that fits my purpose/price.

Answer (score 2):

Try [ECIA Authorized](https://www.eciaauthorized.com/en).

You can get a pretty good idea of what's popular by who carries what and how many they have on hand.

Comment: https://www.findchips.com would be similar also.

Answer (score 0):

Try the big distributors too.  In the US, Digikey.com and Mouser.com.  Good filtering for sizes, values, SMD, thruhole, etc.

PEConnectors.com for sockets, wirewrap, etc.  Lot easier to find those kind of parts than the above 2.

Sometimes Arrow.com, Avnet.com.